# copy the object.keys to new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, for-loop

how can I copy one or all the Object.keys to new object literals
example:

```
  let obj = [
    {
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "cat"
    },
    {
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "cat"
    },
    {
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "dog"
    },
    {
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "dog"
    },

    ]
```

output is like this :

```
{ 
cat: { name: "value1", age: "value2"},
dog: { name: "value1", age: "value2"}
}
```

should we make the temporary object to duplicate it and then assigned it to newObj?
i do like to know with explaining so i would be understanding it,
that is just for example, and how if the groups have a lot of kind group, we should create a function for that, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through every items in your array, process the data, and assign the result to a new object :

```js
let array_of_objects = [{
    name: "value1",
    age: "value2",
    gender: "value3",
    group: "cat"
  },
  {
    name: "value1",
    age: "value2",
    gender: "value3",
    group: "cat"
  },
  {
    name: "value1",
    age: "value2",
    gender: "value3",
    group: "dog"
  },
  {
    name: "value1",
    age: "value2",
    gender: "value3",
    group: "dog"
  },

]

let result = {};

array_of_objects.forEach(animal =>
  result[animal.group] = {
      name: animal.name,
      age: animal.age
    }
  );

console.log(result);
```

Explanations :

1. We create a result object which will collect the data in the wanted format.
2. The forEach method allows us to loop through the array. During every loop, an element is called `animal`.
3. Then the object `result` receives its previous values thanks to the spread notation `...result` plus new keys thanks to the `[animal.group]` part of the code. Note that this notation is between squares because the key needs to be evaluated.

Note : With this implementation, new `cat` values will for instance override the previous ones, but it's not totally clear in your question what you want to do when you have two `cat` in your dataset.

Comment: can we not use spread syntax ?? i do like to know to now use spread syntax @PierreCapo

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (one of the many alternatives):

```js
const array_of_objects = [{ name: "value1", age: "value2", gender: "value3", group: "cat" }, { name: "value1", age: "value2", gender: "value3", group: "cat" }, { name: "value1", age: "value2", gender: "value3", group: "dog" }, { name: "value1", age: "value2", gender: "value3", group: "dog" }, ];

const result = {};
for (const obj of array_of_objects) result[obj.group] = Object.assign({}, obj);

console.log(result);
```

`Object.assign` will evaluate the (enumerable) properties from the object(s) given as second (third, ...) argument and store those in the object passed as first argument. The resulting object is returned and represents thus a (shallow) copy.

The same can be achieved with the more modern spread syntax.

If you only want to copy *some* specific properties, not all, then you can just use a simple assignment per key. That is not really challenging as an answer and I suppose you don't have a problem writing the following in the loop body:

```
const copy = {};
copy.name = obj.name;
// copy anything else here ...
result[obj.group] = copy; // store it in the overall result object
```

If you want something cooler, then we're back at ES6 syntax:

```
const {name, age} = obj;
result[obj.group] = {name, age};
```

Comment: thank you mr handsome :D, how about if we just want the name and age with Object.assign ?? @trincot

Comment: Well, then you don't use `Object.assign`, but just assign the values to the keys you want. That is plain simple, right? But if you want to have a generic solution where you don't know the object keys, then `Object.assign` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily using `Array#reduce()` and object destructuring

```js
const res = data.reduce((a, {group, gender, ...rest})=>{
   a[group] = {...rest}
   return a
},{})
    
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "cat"
    },
    {
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "cat"
    },
    {
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "dog"
    },
    {
      name: "value1",
      age: "value2",
      gender: "value3",
      group: "dog"
    },

  ]
</script>
```

Comment: how about if dont use reduce and not spread syntax? @charlietfl

Comment: Here's a way using array of fields you do want https://jsfiddle.net/sjg3qhba/ that does not use any ES6 features